# App stops debugging if I change the iCloud switch under Documents And Data. Keeps running on the Phone

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud, uimanageddocument

I am integrating iCloud in my App using an `UIManagedDocument`. The PSC options are set when the document is initialized, and because I am debugging I always force the app to use iCloud whithout asking the user.

Everythings seems to work as expected but if on the phone or the pad I go to:

**Settings** -> **iCloud** -> **Document & Data**

and I turn **off** (if on) or **on** (if off) the `UISwitch` related to my App, it crashes without explanations.

What should I check/investigate? Am I supposed to intercept some kind of notification and do something?

*Note:* I am targeting iOS7 and from the documentation I understood the UIManagedDocument handling from local to ubiquity is handled automatically now, isn't it?

****Additional info***: There is not exception in XCode, the app simply stops running in debug and jumps to `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`. On the phone/pad it keeps running, on XCode I can only restart it.

Nicola

Comment: What is the exception if the app is running in Xcode when this happens? Is it the OS terminating the app because the access has changed (just like happens for access to photos / etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app is getting sent SIGKILL to force it to restart.   Apparently this will happen whenever the permissions are changed.  However I think this might be a new Xcode bug because my app behaves normally when not connected to Xcode and the usual checks for iCloud settings changes work fine.